# Filtering json result for values using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a problem filtering JSON results with jq.

I have the following JSON result:

```
{"result":
[
"id":"799dbd172f409c65","status":"active","plan":{"planid":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Enterprise","externally_managed":true}}
"id":"a00eb4acb5905100","status":"active","plan":{"planid":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Enterprise","externally_managed":false}}
"id":"8e09545457675ed2","status":"active","plan":{"planid":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Enterprise","externally_managed":true}}
]}
```

I'd to get a list of IDs for accounts that have "externally_managed":true.

I tried using the following JR, but I failed again and again and again...

```
jq -r '.result[] | select( .externally_managed | contains("true")) | "\(.id)"'
jq -r '.result[] | select( .externally_managed == true) | "\(.id)"'
jq -r '.result[] | select( .externally_managed|tostring == "true") | "\(.id)"'
```

The expected result in this case is:

```
799dbd172f409c65
8e09545457675ed2
```

any assistance will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Have a good one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON looks more like this (curly braces around objects, and commas between array items):

```json
{"result":
[
{"id":"799dbd172f409c65","status":"active","plan":{"planid":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Enterprise","externally_managed":true}},
{"id":"a00eb4acb5905100","status":"active","plan":{"planid":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Enterprise","externally_managed":false}},
{"id":"8e09545457675ed2","status":"active","plan":{"planid":"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"Enterprise","externally_managed":true}}
]}
```

All three of your attempts miss descending into the `.plan` object. Apart from that, all do work fine, only the first one would need a conversion to a string before applying `contains` (as you are already doing in the third one):

```sh
$ jq -r '.result[] | select(.plan.externally_managed|tostring | contains("true")) | "\(.id)"'
799dbd172f409c65
8e09545457675ed2

$ jq -r '.result[] | select(.plan.externally_managed == true) | "\(.id)"'
799dbd172f409c65
8e09545457675ed2

$ jq -r '.result[] | select(.plan.externally_managed|tostring == "true") | "\(.id)"'
799dbd172f409c65
8e09545457675ed2
```

Here's another, shorter one which directly uses the boolean value for `select`, and omits converting the value of `.id` into a string (which it is alrady, at least in your sample data):

```sh
$ jq -r '.result[] | select(.plan.externally_managed).id'
799dbd172f409c65
8e09545457675ed2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/T7CJPTda4v)